How to properly send a bare_call from a pallet to a smart contract
I'm trying to make a pallet -> contract call, using the bare_call function.
pub fn call_smart_contract(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            dest: T::AccountId,
            mut selector: Vec<u8>,
            arg: u32,
            gas_limit: Weight,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            // Check against unbounded input
            ensure!(selector.len() < MAX_LENGTH, Error::<T>::InputTooLarge);
            // Amount to transfer
            let value: BalanceOf<T> = Default::default();
            let mut arg_enc: Vec<u8> = arg.encode();
            let mut data = Vec::new();
            data.append(&mut selector);
            data.append(&mut arg_enc);


            // Do the actual call to the smart contract function
            pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
                who,
                dest.clone(),
                value,
                gas_limit,
                None,
                data,
                DebugInfo::Skip,
                CollectEvents::Skip,
                Determinism::Enforced
            );

            Self::deposit_event(Event::CalledContractFromPallet(dest));
            Ok(())
        }

This is the extrinsics I'm calling from the pallet, but nothing seems to happen. I'm encoding the selector + data correctly?
The arg is just a u32 that the contract receives to store.
The node I'm using is just the Cumulus template with the Contracts pallet added, the version is from the branch release-polkadot-1.10.0.
Any tips in how to debug what is happening is welcome as well, thanks!!

Found the issue, it was how I was sending the selector.
My function selector was 0xaaaccc so in the extrinsics I was sending the selector without modifications 0xaaaccc.
But actually it needs to have 0x00 in the beggining, so the solution was to send the selector as 0x00aaaccc.
